# Windows scheduled task interactive mode (GUI)

Tags: windows-xp, task-scheduler, interactive

I am trying to run an application (Selenium test) through the task scheduler in a Windows XP virtual machine guest that allows for desktop interaction (keyboard pressing, movement through Firefox). I have tried to run a batch that calls `psexec -i`, but the application is still failing.

How can I have a scheduled task run without users logging into the system? The test can run correctly if the user is logged into the system, but not when it is scheduled to run at a specific time.

Comment: I have had ungodly troubles with task scheduler.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but I would recommend finding another task that is able to do this (e.g Windows Update) and see if there is a clue in their configuration.

Comment: Umm, …, you want the application to run interactively on a PC where nobody is logged in?  I doubt that that is possible.